# React-Native: Testing Custom Context Provider hook functions with or without React Native Testing Library

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-context

I can not wrap my head around how to test the functions provided by my chain of ContextProviders in React-Native properly. All the sources I found are either using mocking build-in context functions only spying on those being called, but I want to properly test them, like any other unit.
The closes source I got was this: https://www.samdawson.dev/article/react-context-testing#behavioral-testing-approaches still I was unable to adopt the reasoning in there.

Now the first Component in question looks (very simplified) like this:

```
export type Ontology = {
  ontologyIsInitialized: boolean;
  getNodes: (
    type: NodeType,
    name?: string,
  ) => Results<Node & Realm.Object>;

const OntologyContext = React.createContext<Ontology>(null);

const OntologyProvider = ({  children, testing = false  }) => {
  const [ontologyIsInitialized, setInitialized] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const ontologyRef = useRef<Realm>(null);

   useEffect(() => {
    if (!ontologyIsInitialized || !ontologyRef.current) {
      Realm.open(testing ? api.testConfig : api.ontologyConfig).then(ontology => {
        ontologyRef.current = ontology;
        setInitialized(true);
      });
    }

    return () => {
      // cleanup function
      setInitialized(false);
      const ontology = ontologyRef.current;
      if (ontology) {
        ontologyRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const getNodes = (
    type: NodeType,
    name?: string,
  ): Results<Node & Realm.Object> => {
    const ontology = ontologyRef.current;
    if (type) {
      return ontology
        .objects<Node>('Node')
        .filtered('type == $0 && name ==[c] $1', type, name);
    }

    return ontology.objects<Node>('Node').filtered('name == $0', name);
  };

  return (
    <OntologyContext.Provider
      value={{
        ontologyIsInitialized,
        getNodes,
      }}>
      {children}
    </OntologyContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useOntology = (testing = false) => {
  const ontology = useContext(OntologyContext);
  if (ontology == null && !testing) {
    throw new Error('useOntology() called outside of a OntologyProvider?');
  }

  return ontology;
};

export { OntologyProvider, useOntology };
```

Now regarding the tests that's how far I could get it before running into troubles with the context and custom export methods (here getNodes):

```
// import '@testing-library/jest-native';
import { act, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NodeType } from './model';
import { OntologyProvider, useOntology } from './OntologyProvider';

const OntologyProviderTester = () => {

  const [testIsInitialized, setInitialized] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const {
    ontologyIsInitialized,
    createNode,
    getNodes,
  } = useOntology();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ontologyIsInitialized) {
      console.log('test ontology is initialized now');
      setInitialized(true);
    }
    return () => {
      // cleanup function
      setInitialized(false);
    }
  }, [ontologyIsInitialized]);

  return (
    <>{testIsInitialized && <View testID='the1'>Test is initialized: {testIsInitialized}</View>}</>
  );
}

describe("Nodes", () => {

  it("test creation", async () => {
    const provider = render(
      <OntologyProvider testing={true}>
        <OntologyProviderTester />
      </OntologyProvider>
    );
    await waitFor(() => provider.getByTestId('the1'));

    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useOntology(true));
    await waitForNextUpdate();

    await act(async () => {
      result.current.createNode(NodeType.Complex, 'Peter Pan');
    })
  });

});
```

As you can see, I apply the config for realm based on a variable and use **api.testConfig** instead of **api.ontologyConfig** but beside this, I want it to behave identically to how it would when used by other components. My problem is that my test component does not get the update of ontologyIsInitialized being changed to true after initialization of the provider.
So it looks like the waiting for the init does not work. I also get the confusing error:

```
 console.error
    Warning: You called act(async () => ...) without await. This could lead to unexpected testing behaviour, interleaving multiple act calls and mixing their scopes. You should - await act(async () => ...);
```

which is confusing because I do call waitFor and act with await!

Beside this is there any other way to test the methods exported via useOntology directly?
I don't want to create a fake consumer component, and I really don't want to test side effects on it, what I need is to unit test the exported functions directly!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

YEAH, I finally found a way to properly unit test the hook. And its much simpler and more elegant that any approach of all the videos on youtube about hook testing, actually the react documentation pointed it out:

import { act, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { waitFor } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import React from 'react';
import { NodeType } from './model';
import { OntologyProvider, useOntology } from './OntologyProvider';

```
describe("Nodes", () => {

  it("node creation", async () => {
    const wrapper = ({ children }) => <OntologyProvider testing={true}>{children}</OntologyProvider>
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useOntology(true), { wrapper });
    await waitFor(() => result.current.ontologyIsInitialized);
    await act(async () => {
      result.current.createNode(NodeType.Complex, 'Peter Pan');
    })
  });

});
```